# How can I create a triangular matrix based on a vector, in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, triangular

Let's say I've got a vector like this one:

```
A = [101:105]
```

Which is really:

```
[ 101, 102, 103, 104, 105 ]
```

And I'd like to use only vector/matrix functions and operators to produces the matrix:

```
101 102 103 104 105
102 103 104 105 0
103 104 105 0   0
104 105 0   0   0
105 0   0   0   0
```

or the following matrix:

```
101 102 103 104 105
0   101 102 103 104
0   0   101 102 103
0   0   0   101 102
0   0   0   0   101
```

Any ideas anyone?

(I'm very much a novice in MATLAB, but I've been saddled this stuff...)

Comment: Sounds like a homework task to me - if not, why are you not allowed to loop it all out? Note that if this is homework, it is still a valid question on SO, but it should have the [homework] tag.

Comment: I am allowed to loop it out; I've been told that loops incur a significant performance penalty. So I've been wracking my brains trying to figure out how to avoid loops, and finally decided to ask on SO.

Comment: Something tells me that someone with 1834 reputation is not posting homework assignments to SO.

Comment: Yeah, I know it sounds like a homework thing; It's just a case where I'm taking over the work from a consultant that my company can no longer afford. I don't know enough about MATLAB to not sound like a newbie.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`hankel(A)` will get you the first matrix

`triu(toeplitz(A))` will get you the second one.

--Loren

Comment: Of course!  I completely forgot that these are common enough to have names.  It's been years since I did anything serious with these...

Answer (score 3):

The best solutions are listed by [Loren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000535/how-can-i-create-a-triangular-matrix-based-on-a-vector-in-matlab/1000889#1000889). It's also possible to create these matrices using [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html):

```
vec = 101:105;
A = full(spdiags(repmat(vec,5,1),0:4,5,5));  % The second matrix
B = fliplr(full(spdiags(repmat(fliplr(vec),5,1),0:4,5,5)));  % The first matrix
```

I recall creating banded matrices like this before I found out about some of the built-in functions Loren mentioned. It's not nearly as simple and clean as using those, but it worked. =)

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd go about it is to create a matrix `A`:

```
101 102 103 104 105
101 102 103 104 105
101 102 103 104 105
101 102 103 104 105
101 102 103 104 105
```

And then find a matrix `B` such that when you multiply `A*B` you'll get the result you want.  Basically do the linear algebra on paper first and then have Matlab do the calculation.

Comment: I don't actually know how to use linear algebra to convert A into what I want. It's kinda like trying to do a linearly-increasing shift on each of the rows... I guess I'll try to figure out something for any NxN matrix... not sure if there is one...

Answer (score 2):

For generating such triangular matrices with such a regular pattern, use the toeplitz function, e.g.

```
m=toeplitz([1,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4])
```

for the other case, use `rot90(m)`